# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loading') Vitest + Pinia + Nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, pinia, vitest

I'm trying to create a component test using Nuxt 3, Vitest and Pinia.

**Everytime i try to run my test i get:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loading')
 ❯ pages/login/index.vue:33:31
     31| 
     32|         <v-btn
     33|           :loading="userStore.loading"
       |                               ^
     34|           :disabled="!formInvalid"
     35|           type="submit"
```

This means somehow the Pinia store is not defined right?
How can I correctly initialize the store inside a component test? [The Pinia docs don't provide any clues](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#unit-testing-components), as I'm not testing the store itself, but a component that depends on the store.

**This is my test code:**

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/vue'
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'

import Login from '@/pages/login/index.vue'

describe('Login', () => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({ components, directives })

  it('render button correctly', async () => {
    const pinia = createTestingPinia({ initialState: { user: { loading: false } } })

    render(Login, {
      global: {
        plugins: [vuetify, pinia],
        stubs: {
          SystemVersions: true
        },

        mocks: {
          $t: (msg: string) => msg,
          required: () => true,
          isEmail: () => true
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

**This is the component that I'm trying to test:**

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <v-form v-model="formInvalid" @submit.prevent="login" class="login-form">
        <h1 class="loginTitle">{{ $t('login.title') }}</h1>
        <h2 class="loginSubtitle">{{ $t('login.sub_title') }}</h2>
        <h1 class="fieldLabel">Email</h1>
        <v-text-field
          variant="outlined"
          v-model="emailAddress"
          label="E-mail"
          placeholder="john@doe.com"
          :rules="[required, isEmail]"
          :error="error"
        />
        <h1 class="fieldLabel">Password</h1>
        <v-text-field
          variant="outlined"
          v-model="password"
          type="password"
          label="Password"
          :rules="[required]"
          class="mb-0"
        />
      

        <v-btn
          :loading="userStore.loading"
          :disabled="!formInvalid"
          type="submit"
          variant="flat"
          color="primary"
          block
          :error="error"
          class="mb-6"
          data-testid="loginBtn"
          >Log in</v-btn
        >

       
        <v-alert
          v-if="error"
          closable
          class="mt-2"
          title="Invalid credentials"
          text="Please check your e-mail and password"
          type="error"
          variant="tonal"
        ></v-alert>
      </v-form>
    </div>
    <system-versions />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  name: 'Login',
  layout: 'login-layout',
  auth: {
    unauthenticatedOnly: true,
    navigateAuthenticatedTo: '/shows'
  }
})

const formInvalid = ref(true)
const emailAddress = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const error = ref(false)
const rateLimitReached = ref(false)

const userStore = useUserStore()

const login = () => {
  error.value = false
  rateLimitReached.value = false
  userStore
    .logInUser({
      emailAddress: emailAddress.value,
      password: password.value
    })
    .then((status: number) => {
      if (status === 400) {
        error.value = true
      }
      if (status === 429) {
        rateLimitReached.value = true
      }
    })
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.loginTitle {
  @include text-style-display-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginSubtitle {
  @include text-style-body;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: $color-ink-lightest;
}

.logo {
  max-width: rem(55px);
  width: auto;
}

.actions {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.login-form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  align-self: center;

  .fieldLabel {
    font-weight: bold;
    @include text-style-heading;
  }
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

@include mobile {
  .login-form {
    max-width: rem(480px);
    min-width: rem(250px);
  }
}
</style>
```

**This is the store that is being used:**

```
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  //
  //  User login/logout logic & user Permissions
  //
  const user = ref<any>()
  const loading = ref<boolean>(false)
  async function logInUser(credentials: { emailAddress: string; password: string }) {
    const { signIn, data } = useAuth()
    loading.value = true
    try {
      await signIn(
        { email_address: credentials.emailAddress, password: credentials.password },
        { callbackUrl: '/shows' }
      )
      user.value = data.value
      loading.value = false
   
    
      return 200
    } catch (e: any) {
      loading.value = false
      return e.status
    }
  }

 

  return {
    user,
    loading,
    logInUser,
   ....
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show us the package version of pinia and nuxt?